# Modelling time until event without event probability itself

Tags: regression, survival

Imagine a study in which the time until some kind of uptake of aftercare is measured; there are two treatment groups (intervention vs. control). I want to know whether the treatment has an effect on the time until uptake of aftercare, but am not particularly interested in the event probability itself (which of course has an implication for time until event). So under the condition that an event (uptake of aftercare) occurred, does the treatment have an effect on the time until the event? Note that my data are interval-censored, i.e. I have 5 measurement points and only know the interval in which the event occurred.

Using standard survival models seems inadequate as they usually model the event probability itself, either. I know that there are some descriptive statistics in survival models measuring the median survival time, but am unsure how to test the above (especially considering interval-censored data).